# Licences Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, licensing

We are now 5 developers and want to use Team Foundation Server 2010. What do we need?

1 Premium/Ultimate Licence and a Professional Version for each developer?
Or does Ultimate already contains more than one licence?

thx
cpt.oneeye

Comment: Disagree with the vote(s) to close.  It is okay to discuss any other SCM/ALM software here, except TFS, it seems.  People do not post these questions on ServerFault.com, because no one answers them.  As long as there are SVN, CVS, Git, etc. questions on here, this is perfectly valid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not an expert and you'll find more information in the licensing [whitepaper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/B/1/7B18407A-AC79-4949-A318-A6636D96F497/Visual%20Studio%202010%20Licensing%20-%20Feb-2010.pdf).

The way I understand it though is that you only get a TFS CAL if visual studio came through an MSDN subscription. That said, if you purchased TFS 2010 then it comes with 5 CAL.

From the whitepaper:

> In addition, a Team Foundation Server CAL is not required for:
>
> ...
>
> - Up to five designated users when Team Foundation Server is purchased through a retail channel...

Comment: Maybe someone can provide additional information, but I *thought* that Professional was the only edition that you could get retail (or MSDN), and that Premium and Ultimate were w/ MSDN only.  I do not have to deal with licensing anymore at my current employer, so I am blissfully oblivious to most of the licensing requirements around TFS 2010.

Comment: @joseph.ferris You are correct. 

If you have MSDN subscriptions for your developers you may have TFS 2010 as part of that and not need to buy it and the MSDN subscriptions will have the CAL.